# How to debug corrupted arguments in a complex Fortran codebase?

Tags: module, fortran, subroutine

I'm debugging a very strange issue of passed-in integer arguments to a Fortran module subroutine being corrupted. The problematic code lies in a complex Fortran code base (the WRF model) and thus the cause of the issue and a minimal working example is difficult if not impossible to isolate.

The problem boils down to an innocuous call to a module subroutine with a set of 18 integers (which signify the starting and ending indices in 3 dimensions, I, J, K in 3 different contexts D, T, M):

```
USE some_module, ONLY : chem_init
! ...

CALL chem_init (...,                       &
               ids , ide , jds , jde , kds , kde ,                &
               ims , ime , jms , jme , kms , kme ,                &
               its , ite , jts , jte , kts , kte                  )
```

Full arguments omitted but mostly consist of arrays and huge, complex derived types. The 18 problematic integers are at the end.

Before the function call, a `write` statement reveals the indices to be, in order:

```
1   225  1  161   1   50
-4  63  -4   27   1   50
1   56   1   20   1   49
```

The subroutine signature looks like:

```
module some_module

subroutine chem_init(..., &
                    ids, ide, jds, jde, kds, kde, &
                    ims, ime, jms, jme, kms, kme, &
                    its, ite, jts, jte, kts, kte)
    implicit none
   ! ... other arguments ...
    integer, intent(in) :: ids, ide, jds, jde, kds, kde, &
                           ims, ime, jms, jme, kms, kme, &
                           its, ite, jts, jte, kts, kte

   ! ...
end subroutine chem_init

end module some_module
```

However, a `write` statement to print all these arguments again now result in corrupted results:

```
0   1   0    1   225   1
161 1   50  -4   63   -4
27  1   50   1   56    1
```

Closer inspection of the results reveal that the resulting arguments have been "shuffled" forward by three: i.e. the original `ids, ide, jds = 1, 225, 1` are now present three arguments forward taking the places of `jde, kds, kde`, and so forth. The source of the `0 1 0` in the corrupted arguments within the subroutine are unknown.

The clues lead me to suspect some kind of corruption in memory due to the complex arguments *before* the 18 integers affected. How can one debug this, given the code base is highly complex and the problem could be anywhere in the previous arguments?

Thank you!

Comment: You did not indicate which Fortran compiler you are using.  Probably, doesn't matter.  All quality compilers have debugging options.  Trying compiling with maximum debugging turned on.  My guess, it's a interface mismatch.

Comment: Thanks @evets. Indeed it happens with both gfortran (recent version(s)) and ifort. Wouldn't an interface mismatch cause a compile-time error? I'll try with a maximum debug setting and lowest optimization - would I have to go through it with a debugger or it'll report errors at compile time?

Comment: You don't tell us enough for us to tell you whether you'll get compile time errors for an interface mismatch problem. If the code has been written properly and there is an interface in scope at the calling point (essentially if the called routine is in a module) you will definitely get an error. This is why you should put all routines in modules. If it is not all bets are off, and it very much depends on the diagnostic capabilities of your compiler.

Comment: @IanBush Apologies for the lack of information. I've modified the question to clarify - and yes, indeed, the problematic routine is within a module. Nothing throws off the compiler - even with ifort `-g -check all`. It is a large codebase, but from what I've seen everything else seems to work properly apart from these arguments.

Comment: If you are using ifort on windows with visual studio, just put a conditional break on the first statement of the routine when ids is 0 and ide is 1.  You may have to use C syntax when specifying the conditional break.

Comment: Please extend your code to a MWE, but at least fill in the parts of the `...` and do not give only the names of the variables but also their declarations in the calling and called routine.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?